# Output a comma-separated list in a column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, csv, string-aggregation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simulating group_concat MySQL function in SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-sql-server-2005)

What's the best way to achieve this?  Edit: in MSSQL 2005

**Table**

```
a   |  b
------------
x   |  1
x   |  4
y   |  6
y   |  1
```

Query:

```
SELECT ? FROM Table
```

so that output is :

```
a   | ListOfB
------------
x   | 1, 4
y   | 6, 1
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In SQL Server you can use `FOR XML PATH`:

```
select distinct a,
  stuff(
  (
    select ','+ cast(b as varchar(10)) 
    from table1 t2 
    where t1.a = t2.a for XML path('')
  ),1,1,'') ListOfB
from table1 t1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/83f96/6)

Comment: To add a bit of complexity, what if t1 and t2 both need to have significant WHERE clauses?  I tried it with the same where clauses in both, which worked, but I wonder if there is a better way.  Maybe others use temp tables?  Basically Table1 is HUGE, and I only need about .01 percent back. so I don't like the idea of doing the sub query on the huge table.  I think I will use a temp table to the the date filtered into essentially Table1, so I can use nearly exactly the query in the Answer.

Comment: @AncientAnt you would need to use the `where` at least on the outer one, you would have to test if you needed it on the inner query