# Return comma separated list of names from comma separate list of IDs

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion

To begin with, please don't hold the crappy database structure against me.  We all have things we have to deal with that we can't change, and I inherited these tables that are deeply ingrained within the application.

Consider these two tables:

```
Personnel
+-----+-------+--------------+
| ID  | Name  | TECHNIQUE_ID |
+-----+-------+--------------+
| 134 | Bob   | 1,2,4        |
+-----+-------+--------------+
| 135 | Mary  | 1,3,4        |
+-----+-------+--------------+
| 136 | Frank | 2            |
+-----+-------+--------------+

Techniques
+-----+----------+
| ID  | Name     |
+-----+----------+
| 1   | Fishing  |
+-----+----------+
| 2   | Archery  |
+-----+----------+
| 3   | Bowling  |
+-----+----------+
| 4   | Hiking   |
+-----+----------+
```

What I need is a listing of each person with a comma-separated list of the techniques they perform.  Essentially turning "1,3,4" into "Fishing,Bowling,Hiking".

I can do this in the CF code by having a nested query, but the report has thousands of rows... which means it could be running tens of thousands of queries just for one report.  I'd prefer to do it all in one query.

Comment: If you're using ColdFusion, then why not do 1 normal DB query, and use either grouped output or "query of query" to combine the results into a comma separated list?

Comment: I mentioned that in the last paragraph.  Basically, the results with just the comma-separated IDs are thousands of records long, with each comma-separated list having up to 20 items in it.  So, with a query of a query I'd be hitting the database 20,000 times per page load.  Not ideal.

Comment: The solution may lie in storing the techniques in a local array, then looping through each comma-separated list as I get to it (vs. hitting the database again.)

Comment: "query of query" does not hit the DB again.  It searches through the query result structure in memory.

Comment: FYI "query of query" is not the same thing as a nested query.  "query of query" is where the `dbtype` parameter equals `query`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do 2 separate queries, one of the `Personnel` tables and one of `Techniques`.

Process the Techniques query result into an associative array, where the index is the ID, and the value is the Name.

When outputting the Personnel.Technique_ID field, process the comma separated value as a list.  Loop through each item in the list, and output the value of the Techniques associative array.

Comment: I struggled for a bit with looping (because I had a cfoutput tag within the loop), but it works great once I simplified it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do the join using `like`:

```
select p.*
from Personnel p join
     Techniques t
     on ','+ p.TECHNIQUE_ID+',' like '%,'+cast(t.id as varchar(255))+',%'
```

Do you really need this as a concatenated string?  Or are separate rows good enough?

Comment: There's no `LIKE` in your query.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Another possibility is to combine Gordon's LIKE code with the [XML Path trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13053078/104223), to return everything in one query.  (I doubt either one will be a speed demon with *really* large tables, but given the schema you inherited ... that is to be expected.)

```
SELECT  p.id,
        STUFF( (  SELECT ','+ cast(name as varchar(10)) 
                  FROM   Techniques t 
                  WHERE  ','+ p.Technique_ID+',' LIKE '%,'+ cast(t.id as varchar(255)) +',%'
                  FOR    XML path('')
                )
                , 1,1,'') TechniqueList
FROM   Personnel p
```

---

(Not really a complete answer, but it is too long for comment ...)

If you are only displaying the information, you could combine [Gordon's query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17029119/104223) with a grouped `cfoutput` to produce the desired output. (Just be sure to order the results `Personnel.name` then `techniques.name`)

**Code:**

```
<cfoutput query="yourQuery" group="id">
    <cfset skills = []>
    <cfoutput>
        <cfset arrayAppend(skills, skillTitle)>
    </cfoutput>

    NAME: #name# | 
    SKILLS: #arrayToList(skills)#<br>
</cfoutput>
```

**Result:**

```
NAME: Bob   | SKILLS: Archery,Fishing,Hiking
NAME: Frank | SKILLS: Archery
NAME: Mary  | SKILLS: Bowling,Fishing,Hiking
```